# Where is socket.io.js file?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io version 6.9.0.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket= io();
```

when I have this code, I can successfully connect with socket server. But I can't find `socket.io.js` file in my local directory `"/socket.io"`.

[directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m94iX.png)

I just found `socket.io.js` is in `\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist` directory. Then how did my `html` file found `socket.io.js` in `/socket`??

Also, how `var socket=io();` code could connect with server eventhough there's no server address and port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` this will make the client load the script from the same origin it was downloaded. For example `localhost`. This means, the target URL is in this case `http://localhost:PORT/socket.io/socket.io.js`. This has **nothing** to do with the location of that file because there is kind of a webserver providing that script ( -> your localhost). The file may be located in a completley different directory.

What happens is, that your client tries to load the source file from `http://localhost:PORT/socket.io/socket.io.js`. What the server now does depends on your server architecture and configuration. For example many prod environments make use of a `reverse-proxy` like so:

```
 location /socket.io/ {
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/socket.io/;
 }
```

This will route the request to another server (running "locally" on your rootserver) on port `3011` in this example. There is a node application (the socket.io server) running and it knows what to do now: serving the `socket.io.js` file.

Once this is done `var socket= io();` will lead to another request (which you can observe in your browsers dev-tools) and then the `socket.io` server knows that there is an incoming `connect` request.

**Conclusion**: 
It depends on how socket.io was implemented where you can find that source file in the end. Many modern clients make use of `react` or `Angular` where those third party sources will be bundled and this bundle is downloaded in the initial request. In this case you'd never find a `socket.io.js` on your client.
If you load the script using a `<script>` tag (as you did) it depends on the target URL and the server behind it where to find the script in the end.

Hope this answers your question.